# Trying to replace SQLite with Postgres, seems I am in the wrong directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have been having this same issue with Heroku deployment now for two days. So much so I have considered just trying to use OpenShift instead, but I am reading Ruby On Rails Tutorial, Second Edition, by Michael Hartl and as you all probably know, they use Heroku. My errors have been deep and involved, so much so I have considered starting over but I feel like I will just end up back at this issue.

As it stands, I read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

> If you are starting a new Rails app, you can make postgres the default database by running:

```
$ rails new -d postgresql
```

When I do this, this is what I encounter:

```
$ rails new -d postgresql
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
```

Comment: the article clearly states 'when starting a new Rails app', not 'when converting an existing app'.

Comment: I am new to this. I assumed since I have just started the app that it was new, rather than existing. Now looking at it I suppose it is existing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rails new
```

Initializes a new Rails application. If you already have an existing Rails application and you want to switch to PostgreSQL skip that like and simply update the Gemfile.

Edit your Gemfile and remove this line:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Replace with this line:

```
gem 'pg'
```

You will also need to update the configuration file as explained in the article. The Heroku article [Getting Started with Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#use-postgres) covers how to convert an existing app.

Moreover, you will have to install PostgreSQL locally, create the database and reload the schema. You will find several articles containing the list of commands required to perform such tasks.

You could potentially avoid installing PostgreSQL locally if you use SQLite for development and PostgreSQL for production, however this is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I edited the Gemfile appropriately, as well, I have edited the config file. Now I am at the Install PostgresSQL portion locally, I however don't have much working here. I tried to do a bundle install to hopefully copy the Gemfile to the Gemfile.lock, but now that's also failing. Undefined local variable or method `‘pg’' for Gemfile
        from /Users/cory/rails_projects/first_app/Gemfile:7

Comment: Make sure the syntax of your gemfile is correct. http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html You may need to study a little bit of Ruby and Rails to better understand what's going on in your app.